# Find a sequence of $3$ tennis players such that their ratings are in increasing/decreasing order

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

At a certain (unrealistic) event, we have infinitely many tennis players lined up who are conveniently numbered $P_1, P_2, P_3 \cdots $. Each player has a certain rating which is unknown to us. A player with a higher rating ALWAYS beats a lower-rated player when the two face off in a game. The only way for us to see if $P_i$ is better than $P_j$ is to have them play a match and based off who wins, we know which person has the higher rating.

Andrew wants to find a subsequence of three players $(P_a, P_b, P_c)$ where $a<b<c$ and either $P_a$ is better than $P_b$ who is better than $P_c$ or $P_a$ is worse than $P_b$ who is worse than $P_c$. The goal is to minimize the number of tennis matches that Andrew must conduct in order to guarantee getting such a triple, even in the worst case scenario.

How would I come up with such an algorithm?

Comment: This is a problem from the [2021 Mathcamp qualifying quiz](https://www.mathcamp.org/qualifying_quiz/current_quiz/), with deadline March 18th. Posting it here is a violation of the MSE contest problem policy. I've flagged this question for the moderators, and I'll make sure the people reading your application know that you cheated.